dpkg: error processing package python3-yaml, llvm-10-tools, llvm-10-dev, python3-pygments, gconf2
im using ubuntu on wsl2 and
the problem began when i tried to install these packages with apt:
apt install clang cmake ninja-build pkg-config

then i faced with this error:
Setting up python3-yaml (5.3.1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-yaml.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-yaml (--configure):
 installed python3-yaml package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up libobjc4:amd64 (10.5.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Setting up libffi-dev:amd64 (3.3-4) ...
Setting up libclang-cpp10 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up ninja-build (1.10.0-1build1) ...
Setting up python3-pygments (2.3.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pygments.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-pygments (--configure):
 installed python3-pygments package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up libz3-4:amd64 (4.8.7-4build1) ...
Setting up libpfm4:amd64 (4.10.1+git20-g7700f49-2) ...
Setting up libclang1-10 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up binfmt-support (2.2.0-2) ...
update-binfmts: warning: /usr/share/binfmts/python3.8: no executable /usr/bin/python3.8 found, but continuing anyway as you request
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/binfmt-support.service → /lib/systemd/system/binfmt-support.service.
Setting up pkg-config (0.29.1-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up libobjc-9-dev:amd64 (9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) ...
Setting up libomp5-10:amd64 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up librhash0:amd64 (1.3.9-1) ...
Setting up libc6-i386 (2.31-0ubuntu9.14) ...
Setting up cmake-data (3.16.3-1ubuntu1.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libjsoncpp1:amd64 (1.7.4-3.1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libtinfo-dev:amd64 (6.2-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up libz3-dev:amd64 (4.8.7-4build1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of llvm-10-tools:
 llvm-10-tools depends on python3-pygments; however:
  Package python3-pygments is not configured yet.
 llvm-10-tools depends on python3-yaml; however:
  Package python3-yaml is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package llvm-10-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libomp-10-dev (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up llvm-10-runtime (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of llvm-10-dev:
 llvm-10-dev depends on llvm-10-tools (= 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1); however:
  Package llvm-10-tools is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package llvm-10-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up lib32gcc-s1 (10.5.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Setting up lib32stdc++6 (10.5.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Setting up cmake (3.16.3-1ubuntu1.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libclang-common-10-dev (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up llvm-10 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up clang-10 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up clang (1:10.0-50~exp1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.14) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.23) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.7.0.dfsg.2-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-yaml
 python3-pygments
 llvm-10-tools
 llvm-10-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

i read this question since it was similar to mine and i tried:
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt install libavahi-glib1 --reinstall
but each of these three commands gaved me the same error:
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-yaml.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-yaml (--configure):
 installed python3-yaml package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up gconf2 (3.2.6-6ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gconf2.postinst: 74: gconf-schemas: not found
dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 installed gconf2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up python3-pygments (2.3.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pygments.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-pygments (--configure):
 installed python3-pygments package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up libavahi-glib1:amd64 (0.7-4ubuntu7.3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of llvm-10-tools:
 llvm-10-tools depends on python3-pygments; however:
  Package python3-pygments is not configured yet.
 llvm-10-tools depends on python3-yaml; however:
  Package python3-yaml is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package llvm-10-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of llvm-10-dev:
 llvm-10-dev depends on llvm-10-tools (= 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1); however:
  Package llvm-10-tools is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package llvm-10-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.14) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-yaml
 gconf2
 python3-pygments
 llvm-10-tools
 llvm-10-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

i would appreciate any help for fixing this problem 

You don't mention it, so I have to ask, did you run sudo apt update first?

yeah, of course  i run the update and upgrade

That's good.  You probably wouldn't believe how many people don't do this first.

Do other packages with different dependencies install okay?

i really didn't know that. i thought everyone first solution was  apt update

unfortunately, no packages install properly, this morning I was trying to install gh (github cli) and it installed successfully but I faced the dpkg error again. gh is  working but when i tried to install it , i faced the dpkg error

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
